# Dictionary<string,string> to Dictionary<Control,object> using IEnumerable<T>.Select()

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda, ienumerable

I have a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>` containing control ID and appropriate data column to data bind:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Label1", "FooCount" },
    { "Label2", "BarCount" }
};
```

I use it that way:

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var row = ((DataRowView)FormView1.DataItem).Row;
    Dictionary<Control, object> newOne = dic.ToDictionary(
        k => FormView1.FindControl(k.Key)),
        k => row[k.Value]);
}
```

So I'm using `IEnumerable<T>.ToDictionary(Func<T>, Func<T>)`.

Is it possbile to do the same using  `IEnumerable<T>.Select(Func<T>)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, but the return value will be an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Control, object>>` rather than a `Dictionary<Control, object>`:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Control, object>> newOne = dic.Select(
    k => new KeyValuePair<Control, object>(FormView1.FindControl(k.Key), 
                                           row[k.Value]));
```

(untested)

Comment: I can't figure out how to do that exactly? What `Func<T>` can do that?